# VB.NET - Button Resizing

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I'm writing a full screen 'kiosk-esque' application and I want the buttons to fit accordingly.

Currently when the form opens, I have the buttons anchored and they stretch vertically, but I want them to resize horizontally as well?

Is there an easy way to do this?
[image: In editor view]
[image: In application view]

Comment: WinForms (at least I think - VisualStudio/VB.net/Windows Form Application)

Answer (score 1):

For WinForms, use a `TableLayoutPanel` with 3 columns, with widths set to 33.33% for your example. Put a button in each panel, set their Dock properties to Fill, and use Anchors to stretch the entire `TableLayoutPanel`.

For WPF you would use a `Grid` control.

Comment: This seems to be working, sort of... I'm using `With TBL_CONTAINER.ColumnStyles(3)
            .SizeType = SizeType.Absolute
            .Width = 33.33
        End With`
For the code to set the width, but it crashes the application on start? Any idea?

Comment: **Update:** I found a 'fancy' way of doing the width in the properties. Thanks

Comment: You should use `SizeType.Percent` instead of `SizeType.Absolute`

Answer (score 0):

Used code to do it.Just add this code to your form.

```
Private Sub Form1_SizeChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.SizeChanged
    Button1.Width = (Me.Width - 100) / 3 - 10 'That "10" in the last comes from 15*2/3 .So if the space2 is 15 this number must be 10.
    Button2.Width = (Me.Width - 100) / 3 - 10 'That "Me.Width - 100" comes from 2*50 .If you want space1 50,this number must be 100.
    Button3.Width = (Me.Width - 100) / 3 - 10 'Resize the last.
    Me.Button1.Location = New Point(50, Button1.Location.Y) 'Start from 50 in X Coordinate.
    Me.Button2.Location = New Point(Button1.Width + 65, Button2.Location.Y) 'That 65 means "50 + 15".(50 is space1,15 is space2.)
    Me.Button3.Location = New Point(Button1.Width + Button2.Width + 80, Button3.Location.Y) 'As you expected "50 + 15 + 15 = 80" 
    'This works for only 3 buttons(horizontally).Get the logic and improve your code for your button count.
End Sub
```

[image: Here is the image]

You can see the `space1` and `space2` that I used in my code here.That 3 buttons resize horizontaly if your form `SizeChanged`.